# Angular 8. Проблема с событиями между дочерним и родительским компонентами

Tags: angular

Всем привет! Не могу реализовать в Angulare 8 простейшее взаимодействие дочерних и родительских компонентов. Код писал основываясь на статье с Метанита : https://metanit.com/web/angular2/2.10.php.

**Дочерний компонент:**

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core'
import { User } from '../user'
import {
    trigger,
    state,
    style,
    animate,
    transition
} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-item',
    templateUrl: './user-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user-item.component.css'],
    animations: [
        // когда то была анимация
    ],
})

export class UserItemComponent {
@Input() user: User;
@Input() detailsHidden: boolean;
@Output() onSelect: EventEmitter<User> = new EventEmitter<User>();

animationState: string = 'hide';

public select() {
    this.onSelect.emit(this.user);
}
```

**Разметка дочернего компонента:**

```
<button class="main" (click)="select()">{{user.name}}</button>
<div class="item-details" [hidden]="detailsHidden" >
    <p>age : {{user.age}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="user.country">country : {{user.country}}</p>
</div>
```

**Родительский компонент:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'
import { User } from '../user'

@Component({
    selector: 'user-list',
    templateUrl: './user-list.component.html'
})

export class UserListComponent  {
    @Input() users: User[];
    @Input() selectedUser: User;

    select(data : User) {
        alert('zzz');
        //this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    }
}
```

**Разметка родительского компонента**

```
<h1 *ngIf="users">Count of users : {{users.length}}</h1>
<user-item *ngFor="let user of users"
           [user]="user"
           [detailsHidden]="selectedUser != user"
           (select)="select($event)">
</user-item>
```

Собственно при нажатии на кнопки UserItem'a ожидаю увидеть `alert('zzz');`, но на деле тишина. Что делаю не правильно?
Заранее благодарен

Comment: в дочернем компоненте генератор `onSelect` называется, а не `select`. `(onSelect)="select($event)"`

Comment: Действительно! Спасибо большое